# Frobenius method on solving ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

To determine basis of solution using Frobenius method of the ODE $$x^2 y'' + 6x y' + (4x^2 + 6)y = 0$$
I have tried the following but not sure to arrive at the conclusion.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\alpha }(n(n-1)a_{n}+6na_{n}+4a_{n-2}+6a_{n})x^n =0\\  
\implies(n(n-1)a_{n}+6na_{n}+6a_{n} =-4a_{n-2}\\  
\implies(n^2-1+6n+6)a_{n} =-4a_{n-2}\\  
\implies a_{n} = \frac{-4a_{n-2}}{n^2+6n+5}=-\frac{4a_{n-2}}{(n+1)(n+5)}$$
If we plugin $n=0$ we get $a_{-2}$ or if we plugin $n=2$ we get a_{0} however the next value is not providing $a_{1}$.

How to proceed further to find the basis of a solution. Kindly explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made an error in combining the coeffients, it is $n(n-1)=n^2-n$, you computed with $n^2-1$. Then 
$$
(n^2+5n+6)a_n=-4a_{n-2}\implies a_n=-\frac{4a_{n-2}}{(n+2)(n+3)}
$$
However in checking the solution you will find that there is a defect in the lowest degrees. You need the coefficients for the negative powers, as also the full Frobenius method demands, in it you search for a solution of the form $$y(x)=x^r\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$ Instead of re-computing the coefficient relations and finding $r=-2$ and $r=-3$ as valid lowest powers, you can also just set $a_{-3}$ and $a_{-2}$ as the arbitrary integration constants, $a_n=0$ for $n<-3$ and the other coefficients follow from the recursion.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, Thanks a million for your time explaining this.